# Forms based authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, security

If I wanted to make sure that AUTHENTICATED users were denied access to Enroll.aspx and UNAUTHENTICATED users had access how should my "allow/deny users" tags be set in the web.config?

```
<location path="Enroll.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users = "?" />
        <deny users = "?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<allow users="?" />
<deny users="*" />
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```
<authorization>
<allow users = "?" />
<deny users = "*" />
</authorization>
```

Allow anonymous users, deny everyone else.

Comment: Nope... seemed to obvious. I thought the deny users = "*" would deny everyone.